# Accessing both Request and Response in a Jersey Filter

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

In Jersey, one can add a `ContainerRequestFilter` or a `ContainerResponseFilter`

```
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) {
       // logic
   }
}

public class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request,
                                    ContainerResponse response) {
       // logic
    }
}
```

Both are added using PackagesResourceConfig:

```
PackagesResourceConfig prc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.company.xxx");

prc.getContainerRequestFilters().add(new RequestFilter());
prc.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new ResponseFilter());
```

Although the response filter also has access to the request, it is called AFTER the endpoint is called. What we require is the ability to access the request and the response in the same filter BEFORE the endpoint is called. The request filter is called before the endpoint, but does not have access to the response.

There seems to be no way to add a standard `javax.servlet.Filter` which has access to both the `HttpServletRequest` and the `HttpServletResponse`, and is called before the endpoint is invoked.

Thanks

Comment: *...response in the same filter **BEFORE** the endpoint is called.* Why ?? what is the use case ??? What would you filter, if there is no response ???

Comment: the api of another service which has to be called requires this.

Comment: So what ??? still doesn't make sense.

Comment: For cross browser authentication purposes, the external service populates some headers in the response. That's the way it works. One solution is to create the response object manually. But it appears Jersey is limited in comparison with the standard servlet specification. Another issue is that the Jersey container request object does not give access to the underlying HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Whatever the use case it could probably be handled implementing _both_ the request and response filter, and communicating between the two using the `getProperties()` of the ContainerRequest. Add whatever you need from the request filter to the properties and fetch it from the properties in the response filter

Comment: Thanks, but still, where would you put the code - in the filter method inherited from ContainerRequestFilter or the method inherited from ContainerResponseFilter. Only the second has access to the response object, but it's called after the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter anything without calling the endpoint, because that's how the request comes to your service. If you meant without hitting the controller, that's a different story. But even then, you want something like pre-matching response filter, which naturally does not exist. It defeats the purpose of your service. Why not just add whatever header you want on all responses after the controller and any other pieces in the handling chain finish their work?! You can access both the request context and the response context in the response filter, so as Paul mentioned in the comments you could store some information you will need in the requestContext while in the **ContainerRequestFilter**.
JAX-RS spec has some good examples of both filters and interceptors.